# R max and first in data frame j condition

Tags: r

I have a dt created like so:

```
set.seed(12048)
CC <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "B", "D", "D")
PO <- c("PO1", "PO2", "PO3", "PO4", "PO5", "PO6", "PO7", "PO8", "PO9", "PO10")
Rating <- c(1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3)
dt <- data.table(CC, PO, Rating)
```

and which looks like so:

```
    CC   PO Rating
 1:  A  PO1      1
 2:  A  PO2      3
 3:  A  PO3      3
 4:  B  PO4      2
 5:  B  PO5      4
 6:  C  PO6      2
 7:  A  PO7      1
 8:  B  PO8      2
 9:  D  PO9      0
10:  D PO10      3
```

My intention is to be able to find out the first non zero rating and the max rating of each CC.

Here's the code which I have

```
dt[,.(FirstRating=ifelse(length(which(Rating > 0) > 0), .SD[which(Rating > 0)[1]]$Rating, head(.SD, 1)$Rating) , MaxRating=max(Rating)), by="CC"][FirstRating != 0 & MaxRating > FirstRating]
```

This gives me the output I desire

```
   CC FirstRating MaxRating
1:  A           1         3
2:  B           2         4
```

However, this looks very complicated and am not sure if there is a way to keep it simple using the data.table capabilities. Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you not want so see output from C and D?
Here an answer in which for each CC the first and max rating is shown.

EDIT: Imo had a more efficient solution which prevents the .SD comment and copying data.

```
dt[,.(FirstRating = Rating[Rating > 0][1],
      MaxRating = max(Rating)),
   by = CC]
   CC FirstRating MaxRating
1:  A           1         3
2:  B           2         4
3:  C           2         2
4:  D           3         3
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use `.SD`, which often creates a copy of the data.table. For example, `dt[, .(firstRating=Rating[which.max(Rating > 0)], maxRating=max(Rating)), by=CC]` or `dt[, .(firstRating=head(Rating[Rating > 0], 1), maxRating=max(Rating)), by=CC]` will work.

Comment: You are right that is more efficient I will edit my solution thanks